# How to rotate and move an object in precise time frame

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, motion

My task is to rotate and move an object into a new position and rotation in a given time. Say I have to move a cube from `(0,0,0)|(0,0,0)` to `(1,1,1)|(0,90,0)` in 5 seconds. Could anyone explain to me please how to achieve that?

My experiment is:

```
private IEnumerator DoMove(/*float time, Vector3 targetPosition*/)
{
    foreach(WayPoints wp in tposes)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        float duration = wp.timeStamp;
        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 curpos = cube.transform.position;
            Quaternion crot = cube.transform.rotation;
            float time = Vector3.Distance(curpos, wp.position.position) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;
            cube.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(curpos, wp.position.position, time);
            cube.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(crot, wp.position.rotation, time);
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Reached position: " + wp.position.position + " in time: " + Time.time);
    }
}
```

The cube gets to its position in time, but rotation is late. The end position of the cube should be `(2,2,2)|(0,120,0)`, but it stops moving at `(2,2,2)|(0,~110,0)`.

There are two positions I want the cube to be in:

- `(1,1,1)|(0,90,0)` in 5 seconds
- `(2,2,2)|(0,120,0)` in next 4 seconds

[image]

Comment: Well, the cube gets to its position in time, but rotation is late. The end position of the cube should be (2,2,2)|(0,120,0), but it stops moving at (2,2,2)|(0,~110,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was found. I forgot to calculate time steps for rotation as well. Now code looks like:

```
 private IEnumerator DoMove()
    {
        foreach(WayPoints wp in tposes)
        {
            float counter = 0;
            float duration = wp.timeStamp;
            while (counter < duration)
            {
                counter += Time.deltaTime;
                Vector3 curpos = cube.transform.position;
                Quaternion crot = cube.transform.rotation;
                float time = Vector3.Distance(curpos, wp.position.position) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;
                float rtime = Quaternion.Angle(crot, wp.position.rotation) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;
                cube.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(curpos, wp.position.position, time);
                cube.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(crot, wp.position.rotation, rtime);
                yield return null;
            }
            Debug.Log("Reached position: " + cube.transform.position + "|" + cube.transform.rotation.eulerAngles +" in time: " + Time.time);
            Debug.Break();
        }

    }
```

One row did the stuff:

```
float rtime = Quaternion.Angle(crot, wp.position.rotation) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;
```

Thank you for the comments